# Using "lo que" or "que" as the relative pronoun

Tags: gramática

These neuter relative pronouns refer to a situation, an unknown antecedent or concept, **not a specific masculine / feminine noun or pronoun**

I am comfortable with the following usage

> Sé todo lo que haces para mejorar.I know everything that you do to
> improve.

> Dicen que soy guapa, lo que es verdad. They say I'm pretty,which is true.

However, there are some examples where the antecedent is a noun in which **lo que/lo cual** is used but I feel as though **que** should have been used instead. i.e I am having trouble understanding whether the antecedent is specific or not.

1)

> Tengo una **manta** de sobra, lo cual no necesito.I have an extra
> blanket, which I don't need.

**lo cual** is used when the antecedent is not specific so why is it being used here? isn't **la manta** a specific antecedent? shouldn't **que** be used here?

2)

> Panamá tiene acceso a dos océanos, lo que facilita su economía.Panama
> has access to two oceans, which facilitates its economy.

**lo que** is used here since the something being mentioned is **acceso a dos océanos** not the **dos oéanos**.

However, if the something being mentioned was the **dos océanos** then **que** would have been used

> Panamá tiene dos océanos, que facilita su economía. Panama has to two
> oceans, which facilitates its economy.

Am I right?

3)

> Hay **nubes**, lo que indica lluvia. There are clouds, which indicates
> rain.

isn't **nubes**, the something being mentioned a specific feminine noun so why isn't **que** being used

or is it that **there are clouds** is not specific as opposed to **these are the clouds** as in the following sentence?

> estas son las **nubes** que parecen elefantes these are the clouds that
> look like elephants

Assuming "These are + noun..." is specific and "There are + noun" isn't specific, then what about

> estas son las manzanas... vs estas son las manzanas...

or even the following

> una manzana que es roja... vs la manzana que es roja....

since la is specific and una isn't

or what about people - I know quien/es is used for people but if "there are clouds" isn't specific then "there are people" isn't specific also

> Estas son las personas que están tristes these are the people who are sad.

vs

> Hay personas lo que están tristes there are people who are sad

Comment: "Tengo una manta de sobra, lo cual " i don't think this is correct. I believe it should be "la cual". I'm not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I don't know where you got this sentence, but it has a problem.  The simplest fix is

> Tengo una manta de sobra, la cual no necesito.

(because *manta* is feminine).

To answer your question: you wrote, "**lo cual** is used when the antecedent is not specific," but that is not correct.  Go back and look at what you wrote in your previous question.

2) I will make a small correction to your sentence:

> Panamá tiene dos océanos, lo cual facilita su economía.

It's the concept of having two oceans that is the antecedent here, and *lo cual* is a great way to refer back to the *concept* of the phrase before the comma.  Here's how I would think about it in English:

Panama has two oceans, which is a situation that favors economic development.

Notice that the following is different:

> Panamá tiene dos océanos, que han tenido un gran efecto en su historia. | *Panamá has two oceans, which have had a large effect on its history.*

Here, the connection, **que**, refers back to just the noun, "oceans."  (In other words, your analysis was good.)

3) The reason "que" isn't used here is that the thing that indicates rain is the whole phrase or concept ("hay nubes"), as opposed to just the noun ("nubes").

What you said about *clouds* not being specific looks like a pretty good analysis.

Your examples with the *manzanas* (plural) are impossible to respond to because you inadvertently wrote two identical phrases.

Your next example, about the red apple, looks fine, but I don't like your analysis there.  The important point here isn't whether there's a *definite* article (**the**) or an *indefinite* article (**un/una**).

Now let's look at your last example:

> Estas son las personas que están tristes

This is A-OK.  However, your alternative ("Hay personas lo que están tristes") does not work.

Comment: can you explain to me why "Hay personas lo que están tristes¨doesn´t work? thank you!

Comment: @Spanishbeginner - The simplest answer is that a simple connector (*which/que*) is sufficient for that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

To check whether a neuter or a specific-gender (as well as specific-number) relative pronoun is needed in a non-restrictive clause we have to focus on the relative clause and imagine the object of its verb.

If the pronoun is number-specific, a plural antecedent will require a plural verb.

In sentence 1), "lo cual" is wrong because the relative can be expanded into:

- No necesito **una manta de sobra**.

However, this would work:

1') Tengo una manta de sobra, **lo cual** no es necesario.

The generic predicate allows for an infinitival subject:

- No es necesario **tener una manta de sobra**

and this fits in with the definition of conceptual or situational antecedent that is required for "lo que" or "lo cual" to work.

In sentence 2), the antecedent is not merely "access to two oceans", but "the fact that Panama has access to two oceans": this is what fosters its economy.

The sentence *Panamá tiene dos océanos, que facilita su economía* is wrong. With a relative pronoun like "que" number agreement is required:

2') Panamá tiene acceso a dos océanos, que le permite**n** mirar por igual hacia Europa y hacia Asia (... which **enable** it to look towards Europe and Asia alike).

We can of course also say:

2'') Panamá tiene acceso a dos océanos, **lo que/lo cual** le **permite** mirar por igual hacia Europa y hacia Asia (... which **enables** it to look towards Europe and Asia alike)

In sentence 3), the antecedent is not just "nubes" but "el hecho de haber nubes", o "la existencia de nubes".

We can, however, think of a similar sentence in which "nubes" is made the antecedent and a plural verb is required:

3') Hay nubes que **anuncian** lluvia.

Notice that, in the sentence above, since the referent is general we need a restrictive clause that defines it (so the comma needs to be eliminated).